# Pagination on custom query

Tags: query-posts, pagination

I'm using the following code with `query_posts` to put together a custom search:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'species',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
);
```

`$meta_query` is put together with a few segments of code like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST["s_aquarium_H"])) {
    $val = convert_values('size', $size, $_POST["s_aquarium_H"]);
    $aquarium_H = array(
        'key' => 'aquarium_H',
        'value' => $val,
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '<='
    );
    $meta_query[] = $aquarium_H;
}
```

This works perfectly well and is accessed by visiting `/advanced-search/`.

However, my pagination does not. When you click `Next Entries`, the URL changes to `/advanced-search/page/2/` but simply re-opens the Advanced Search form.

I guess this is because I'm using `$_POST`. Is there a way of using pagination with `$_POST` or do I need to change my code to `get_query_var` or something?

---

**EDIT**

My rewrite rules appear to be correct: `/advanced-search/page/2/` displays `pagename: advanced-search, paged: 2` in Monkeyman's Rewrite Analyzer plugin.

[image: Rewrite Rules]

---

**FURTHER EDIT**

My `advanced-search.php` page uses the following code to determine whether it should show the search form or the results. I guess this needs re-writing if I'm to use pagination:

```
<?php if ( isset( $_POST["act"] ) && $_POST["act"] == "s" ) : ?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could go about rewriting this? I guess `GET` instead of `POST` needs to be used?

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you add error catching measures like an else case with a message, on the check for POST being set, or a `wp_die('<pre>'.print_r($args,true).'</pre>');` if no posts are found? etc Give as much information about what the values of all variables are on failure and the path the code is taking

Comment: Also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php , e.g. use an assertion to make sure $val actually is numeric, and not null or a string or NaN or an error object etc

Comment: Hi Tom. The `$args` are displaying correctly in every instance - it's only when I click the `Previous Entries` button that everything goes wrong. I've added another edit to my OP with my suspicions. Could you have a look and see what you think?

Comment: Scrap that, fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this was nothing to do with pagination - as such.

I needed to change my entire form to `GET` method and `$_REQUEST` variables rather than `POST` and `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your query:**

```
'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
```

**Like so:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'species',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
);
```

Should do the trick.. Using Wp-pageNavi? dont forget to add the
wp-pagenavi tag just after the loop ends

```
<div class="navigation"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div>
```

.
Hope This Helps ;)
Cheers, Sagive.

Comment: Hi Sagive. Thanks for this, but the same problem is occurring. I'm wondering if, on top of your code, I need some additional rewrite rules?

Comment: Actually, no, it isn't that - the Rewrite Analyzer plugin says that my rewrite rules are correct.

Comment: Sorry, dont know that plugin but.. have you tried it mate? can you give a link or are you working localy?

Comment: Sorry, can't give you a working URL. I've updated my original post with an image of the results from the Rewrite Analyzer plugin. Basically it shows that my rewrite rules are correct, but even with your code, my pagination isn't working. Any idea? I defined `$wp_query` global too, just in case..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST["s_aquarium_H"])) {
   $_GET["s_aquarium_H"] = $_REQUEST["s_aquarium_H"];
    $val = convert_values('size', $size, $_REQUEST["s_aquarium_H"]);
    $aquarium_H = array(
        'key' => 'aquarium_H',
        'value' => $val,
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '<='
    );
    $meta_query[] = $aquarium_H;
}
```

Comment: Bounty awarded for coming closest to solving the problem.